# Increment/Decrement to only odd values in Kendo Numerictextbox on up/down spinners/keys

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have a Kendo NumericTextBox. When some certain field has some certain values,the range of values for that NumericTextBox would be only odd values.

Setting step to 2 will work if current value is odd value.

So if user enters some value like  22 and clicks on up spinner, it should increase values to 23, then 25 on next click.

If current value is 30 and user clicks on down spinner , it should decrease value to 29 , then  27 on next click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Ek2/8/

```
var numericTextBox = $("#bar").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "d",
    value: 1,
    step: 2, }).data('kendoNumericTextBox');

numericTextBox.element.parent().find('.k-link').mousedown(function () {
    var value = numericTextBox.value();
    if (value % 2 === 0) {
        if ($(this).find('span.k-icon').hasClass('k-i-arrow-n')) {
            numericTextBox.value(value - 1);
        }
        else {
            numericTextBox.value(value + 1);
        }
    } });
```

You can also block entering data from keyboard and set step on 2:

```
$("#foo").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "d",
    value: 1,
    step: 2,
});

$("#foo").attr('readonly', true);
```

Comment: Thanks,It works on up/down spinners. what about on key press?  I wish I could detect whether it's  up or down clicked/pressed on bind event.

Comment: I'm afraid that catch keydown event of the numericTextBox is the only way to do it. Kendo don't provides last spin direction in their api. I updated jsFiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Ek2/9/

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky but might work. You should play with [`step`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox#configuration-step) setting it to 1 or 2 depending on the current value of the numeric text field.

Then you change the value when the spinner is clicked or the value changes. Something like this:

```
function adjustStep() {
    var value = this.value();
    if (value % 2 == 1) {
        number.options.step = 1;
    } else { 
        number.options.step = 2;
    }
}

var number = $("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
    step : 1,
    value : 21,
    spin: adjustStep,
    change: adjustStep
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kF2h7/1/

Comment: Setting step 2 will work once value in textbox gets to odd value but not  for a even value. It seems there is no easy way to detect whether user clicked on  up/down spinner or pressed up/down key.